# WooCommerce woa_remove_header_cart if user not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I want to display the header cart (located on the menu) only if the user is logged in. Here's what I got so far:

```
add_action('init','remove_header_cart_if_user_not_logged_in');

function remove_header_cart_if_user_not_logged_in() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        return;
    } else {
        add_action( 'init', 'woa_remove_header_cart' );

    function woa_remove_header_cart() {
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 60 );
    }
}
```

This code creates an error and prevents my website to display. " The [domain] page isn’t working [domain] is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

The else part alone (woa_remove_header_cart) works well, but when I try to put it inside of the "if user logged in" condition, it generates the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you simplified it to:

```
add_action( 'storefront_header','remove_header_cart_if_user_not_logged_in' );

function remove_header_cart_if_user_not_logged_in() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 60 );
    }
}
```

You are adding two functions to the `init` hook at the same time/priority? It's weird at best, and may be causing your error. I'm also not sure if WP knows the user is logged in by `init`. Don't have time to check now, but you can avoid it. You don't have to remove a function on the `init` hook, you just have to do it before the function is executed. In my example, I'm using the `storefront_header` hook, but since the default (10) priority is lower than `60` it should work.

Comment: Great, I simplified it further, but it should still work.